# Client browser webcam streaming to node server and back

Tags: node.js, networking, browser, stream, webrtc

I've been researching a lot on how to live stream frames coming from the camera on browser, to a node server. This server processes the image, and then is supposed to send the processed image back to the client. I was wondering what the best approach would be. I've seen solutions such as sending frames in chunks to the server, for the server to process. I've looked into webRTC, but came to the conclusion that this works more for client to client connections. Would a simple implementation such as using websockets, or using socket.io suffice?

Comment: What are your latency requirements?  You can definitely get better quality by using MediaRecorder, but it has a higher latency.  You can use the WebRTC stack to keep things realtime, but at the sacrifice of quality.

Comment: It has to be pretty much realtime. The goal is to record frames, get the processed frames back if they are of interest, while also streaming more frames to the server. I hope this is enough explanation.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you use WebRTC, it's going to drop frames and do all sorts of other enhancements to keep the latency low.  Don't be surprised if your bitrate drops to a couple hundred kilobit, or if the frame size goes down to like 320x240 randomly.  It's an appropriate tradeoff if the realtime-ness matters.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I wonder if an implementation in which the image is encoded into base64 to send through webRTC would work aswell. The server would be seen as the peer, and it would simply convert the base64 to an image on the server on the fly.

Comment: No!  Don't do that... why would you base64 encode anything?  You're adding 33% overhead in storage, additional processing, memory usage, defeating the whole point of using WebRTC in the first place, etc. etc.

Comment: I'm very new to javascript ,node and all that, so my bad :) Right now I have a client which records a webcam from the browser, and sends it to a web worker to do the processing. This processing is done by taking the ImageData (Uint8Array). I simply want to move that processing to a server, to offload the client from doing too much. My idea was to send a base64, or maybe a clampedarray, instead of the image itself, because I thought this would be more efficient. The server would then e,g take a message consisting of "process, ImgData". All of this ofcourse happening in realtime.

Comment: Tell us specifically what you're trying to do so we can make a better suggestion.

Comment: I'm using a library called ARJS , which allows to record files through the browser (a-frame) by webcam. The goal is to grab each video frame, detect the markers and look for recognized patterns in the frame. If patterns are found, a virtual object is drawn on top of the canvas of the video frame. This makes the client side heat up a lot which is why I wanted to integrate part of the image processing (written in javascript) over to a node server. I thought sending over the imagedata(Unit8clamped) array to the server, would suffice. This is what is used to process frames and find markers.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work well.  Firstly, you can't send frames as-is to the server, as that would take an enormous amount of bandwidth.  You need a video codec.  WebRTC is what is required here, to keep the latency low, but as I said there are tradeoffs for quality.  This tradeoff might not work for AR... depending on the features you're detecting and their relative size.  The other thing is that now you have to run the codec and scaling, which also takes battery power even when hardware accelerated.  And, even with WebRTC, you now have extra latency.

Comment: Alright , thank you very much for your help! I'll be trying it regardless for experimental purposes, I'm aiming for a resolution of around 400x800, and might downscale to see if features can still be detected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebSockets. But, I'd not recommend it. I don't think you should drop WebRTC, yet. It's not just for client to client connections. You can use a MediaServer like `Kurento` or `Jitsi` to process your frames and return the output. I've seen Kurento samples for adding filters and stuff. You can build your own modules on how to process the frames. I'd recommend that you check the MediaServer and see if it fits your requirements. Use WebSockets only if you are sure that `WebRTC` doesn't work for you.